# Mask and insert hyphen after every 3 digits

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, rhino

I am trying to replace the below string like below:

```
var phone = "9871234567"
result = xxx-xxx-4567
```

Below is the js code I have worked upon, but this is not giving me the correct result.

```
var lastphdigit = phone.replace(/\d(?=(?:\D*\d){4})/g, "x");
var lastphdighyp = lastphdigit.replace(/.{3}(?!$)/g, '$&-'); //xxx-xxx-456-7
```

Comment: `.replace(/\d{3}(?!\d?$)/g, 'xxx-')`, https://regex101.com/r/XNMOer/1

Comment: Are these all US phone numbers?

Comment: what should happen if there are less or more than 10 digits?

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by the comment @depperm gave, why not try this?
We slice off 4 digits from the phone number, starting at the end, and then append it to a static string.

```js
var phone = "9871234567";
var maskedPhone = "xxx-xxx-" + phone.slice(-4);
console.log(maskedPhone)
```

This way, if the amount of digits in the phone number is variable, you will still always get the last 4 digits unmasked.
IF this is a consideration, you should also count the amount of digits in the original phone number, and add x's accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is not necessary for this problem. Using `slice` would be much simpler, just get the last 4 digits

```js
var phone = "9871234567"
console.log(`xxx-xxx-${phone.slice(6)}`)
```

Comment: @depperm What if there are some special characters like brackets,space. For ex,
var phone = "9871234567)" then the result would be xxx-xxx-567). How can we handle this scenario if there are some gargbage characters or parenthesisi,space etc at the end of string. We just need to show the last 4 digits only.

Comment: @KaranNayyar that isn't a common phone number format. This doesn't work if there are dashes between the numbers, in that case I'd recommend Wilco answer. Either way regex isn't necessary

Answer (score 2):

If there should be only digits in the string and your JavaScript environment accepts a lookbehind assertion, you can assert optional digits to the left, match 3 digits while asserting 2 or more digits to the right:

```
(?<=^\d*)\d{3}(?=\d{2,}$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cyfqAT/1)

```js
const phone = "9871234567"
const result = phone.replace(/(?<=^\d*)\d{3}(?=\d{2,}$)/g, "xxx-");
console.log(result);
```

If there are always 10 digits, you can use a match followed by a capture group, and then use that capture group in the replacement.

```
^\d{6}(\d{4})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tmzgwq/1)

```js
const phone = "9871234567"
const result = phone.replace(/^\d{6}(\d{4})$/g, "xxx-xxx-$1");
console.log(result);
```